# Did Obi-wan ever try to contact Anakin after Episode III?

Tags: star-wars

In *Return of The Jedi*, when Luke tries to stir the emotions of his father on the forest moon of Endor, Vader states:

> Obi-Wan once thought as you do...

Does this imply that, at some point between Episode III and IV, Obi-Wan tried to contact Anakin?

Comment: he may just be referring the the conversations they had in episode 3. it would be kinda dumb for obi-wan to try to talk to vader at this point since he already left him for dead.

Comment: But the conversation at Episode III was more an expression of frustration from Obi-Wan, than an attempt to show the good that might still be in him. (That was the case with Luke, that caused the speak in question)

Comment: Vader was hunting down the surviving Jedi after Episode III so it would be pretty dumb for Obi-Wan to try to contact him.

Comment: Not so dumb. Altough he left him for dead, soon he must have learned that Anakin recovered. It not hard to think he would care for him again, since they were so close.

Comment: Also, Obi-Wan tells luke `He is more a machine than man... evil...`. That could have been motivated from the fact of failed attempts of talking to him.

Comment: No, that has to do with the fact that he lost much of his body on Mustafar, and clearly required a bodysuit to help him breathe.

Comment: Star Wars: Tales has a comic where Vader is taunted by Kenobi's force ghost following the destruction of the Death Star in Episode IV. As he sits there in his damaged TIE, he continually tries to punch the ghost and ends up making things 10x worse. It's pretty hilarious.

Comment: "Hey, uh... I know you're Vader now, but we can still have that coffee date, right?"

Comment: @Omegacron Do you have an issue number? That sounds like it would be worth tracking down.

Comment: @numaroth - Issue #16 "The Long, Bad Day". Also in SWT Vol. 4, which is where I saw it. http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Long,_Bad_Day